# How can I get a variable/field name through reflection on properties?

Tags: c#, reflection

Lets say you have:
`PropertyInfo propInfo;` //  Assume it was already initialized with property of a private field
(`private int m_Number`)

If I'll do `propInfo.PropertyType.Name` I guess I will get something like `int32` or `int`.
**Two questions:**

**1**. How can I extract the variable name "m_Number" through `propInfo`.
Note: Once I was able to do so by iterating a `FieldInfo` instead of `propInfo`.

**2**. If I want to use reflection to know all kind of fields of a given class, what should be the right way:

**A**. Iterating over all properties(in assumption every field has a property)
 **B**. Iterating over all the fields directely.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property is not necessarily related to a field - in fact, a property is a little more than a syntactic sugar on top of a pair of functions.

If your code uses some sort of a convention for naming variables that back properties (such as prepending them with `m_`, as in your example) you could rely upon that convention to retrieve the variable name. In all other cases, there is no direct connection, and no way to retrieve that relationship through the reflection API.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your note about `m_`.I can't have any assumption that every field starts with m_, it was just for example.   Anyway, do you think that iterating over fields directly is better? (Only the fields are the main interest of mine in the class instances I investigate using reflection)

Comment: @JavaSa There is no ironclad way to find a connection between a property and a field. If your main interest is fields, then you should start with the list of fields, and try to deduce the names of properties from them. However, since there is no direct relationship, you may find fields with no properties, as well as properties with no fields.